# How to get clicked word Index in textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Get index of word in a textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3TSE.png)

I want to get the index of word "Amit" as 3 from the textbox, excluding any space/punctuation marks on mouse click event. As described in the snippet.

Currently I am using the following to get character position of the clicked word, but what I want is the word position using the .on function in jQuery.

```
$("#idTable1 > tbody > tr").on('click', function (e) 
{
var start = document.getElementById("inputTxt").selectionStart;
var end = document.getElementById("inputTxt").selectionEnd;
```

> Edit: If the word selected is repeated in the sentence it should fecth
>   the index of the selected word and not the first/remaining occurances
>   Example: My name is Amit. Amit is 22 years old. 
>   So, if I select "Amit" in Amit is 22 years old, it should give me the appropriate index of mouse click that is index -> 5

```
My -> 0
name -> 1
is -> 2
Amit -> 3
. -> 4
Amit -> 5
is -> 6
22 -> 7
years -> 8
old -> 9
```

So, if I select any word out of that sentence, it should give me the appropriate word index.

Any pointers would be helpful to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code snippets.

```
var text = document.getElementById("inputTxt").value;
console.log(text.split(" ").indexOf("Amit"));
//--------->split the text and find the index
```

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idTable1 > tbody > tr").on('click', function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById("inputTxt").value;
    console.log(text.split(" ").indexOf("Amit"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="idTable1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="inputTxt" value="My Name Is Amit" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Click here</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

You can use the following code snippet for getting the index of mouse selected word with `element.selectionStart` property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idTable1 > tbody > tr").on('click', function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById("inputTxt").value,
      element = $("#inputTxt")[0],
      arr1 = text.split(" "),
      length = 0,
      selectIndex = element.selectionStart;
    if (selectIndex == 0)
      console.log(arr1.indexOf(arr1[0]));
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {            
        length = length + arr1[i].length + 1;
        if (length == selectIndex) {
          console.log(i + 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="idTable1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="inputTxt" value="My name is Amit. Amit is 22 years old." />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not exactly what I wanted, I want to get the index of the selected word on mouse click. You are hard-coding "Amit" in the .IndexOf() method. Please update your answer

Comment: @amitgupta I've updated the answer for mouse selection word.

Comment: Thanks for writing .but this will not work when we will have duplicate word in the string.like in string "amit, my name is amit",if i select amit of index 4 position it will return me the index as 0.please update on this.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful for me.

Comment: You can mark this as answer if it is really helped you, by checking the tick icon near the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** try this

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '#idTable1 > tbody > tr', function (e) {
  var ret = getSelectedWordIndex($("#inputTxt").val(), window.getSelection().toString(), $("#inputTxt")[0].selectionStart, $("#inputTxt")[0].selectionEnd);
  console.log(ret);
 });
 
 function getSelectedWordIndex(fullText, selectedText, start, end){
  var sp = fullText.split(" "),
  pointer = 0,
  result = false;
  $.each(sp, function(i,e){
   if(!result){
    if(e == selectedText){
     if(pointer == start){
      result = sp.indexOf(selectedText, i);
      return false;
     }
    }
    pointer = pointer + e.length + 1;
   }
  });
  return result;
 }
})
```

```html
<table id="idTable1"><tbody><tr><td><button>clickme</button></td></tr></tbody></table>

<textarea id="inputTxt" style="width:100%" >abc def abc def abc def abc def abc def abc def</textarea>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for writing .but this will not work when we will have duplicate word in the string.like in string "amit, my name is amit",if i select amit of index 4 position it will return me the index as 0.but i want index as 4.please update on this.

Comment: you dont say that in your question. who know's

Comment: Not exactly, but got an Idea.In this ,sometimes i am getting response as false too when it contain space .which it should not return.Also when string contain delimiters or dot it is not returning the index correctly.

Comment: omg, 1. we solve your 1st question, but you want duplicate allowed. 2. we solve the duplicate case, but now you want to the sentence not single word. i think next time you should explain your question completely, so these people not doing same work twice or even more. anyway, get the sentence or hack the dot is still possible, just improve my code or john R code. good luck